# alarmManager.cancel not working

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, repeat

I'm  trying to stop a repeating alarm.

 
I already looked all over the web for solution, but my code seems fine...

Still it doesn't stop the alarm...
Here's a little bit of code (FM is a file-writing object)

```
public void StartAlarm() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     Calendar alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
     alarm.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
     alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
     long alarmCal=alarm.getTimeInMillis();
     if (alarmCal<=new Date().getTime()) {
        alarm.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
     }
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarm.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
     FM.Write("startAlarm()");
     }


 public void StopAlarm() {
        if (isAlarmRunning()) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
             PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(sender);
            FM.Write("alarm canceled");
            isAlarmRunning();
        }
public boolean isAlarmRunning() {
    Intent intentToCheck = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AlarmReciever.class);
    boolean alarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intentToCheck,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null;
    FM.Write("alarm = "+alarm);
    if (!alarm) {
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in both function

```
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,     intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: in place of 0 have some number say 1234

Comment: I added isAlarmRunning to the first post.
Im using these functions in a toggle button in my main activity.
and adding in both didn't work...

Comment: I think problem is somewhere with isAlarmRunning try running app without using it once

Comment: isAlarmRunning() func checks for a PendingIntent which is not same as the alarm being you set it return true even if the alarm was deleted

Comment: so how can I make it check for registered alarm?

Comment: add a boolean in shared preferences when alarm is set and put the value false when u cancel it

Comment: But if I have a broadcastReciever that runs on boot, and the phone restarts it will think that the alarm is running, but it isn't...
What happens if you set the same alarm again (to the same hour), will it kill the previuos alarm?

Answer (score 3):

How are you verifying that the alarm is still there? You need to use an equivalent `PendingIntent` (same intent, same flags) to stop the alarm, and it does work. BTW, your `isAlarmRunning()` method checks whether a `PendingIntent` exists, which is not the same as the alarm being registered. It could return `true` even though the alarm has been deleted.

Comment: So how can I check if the alarm is registerd?

Comment: You can't. There is no API for that. You cancel it or overwrite it only.

Comment: Agree with @Nikolar. This is exactly what is happening with me.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with [Nokolay Elenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242930/nikolay-elenkov), answer; just as mentioned from the question's comments the user is setting a `ToggleButton` based on whether the `PendingIntent` is active or not. And this is something different than if the alarm still registered or not.

And to match both things you have to cancel both of them; i.e. cancel the alarm, and cancel the `PendingIntent`.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
 myToggleButton.setChecked(pendingIntent != null);

 // Setting the alarm
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.setRepeating();


 // Canceling the alarm
 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

 // canceling the pendingIntent
 PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE).cancel();
```